# How to make a list of products from a custom variable?

Tags: magento2, product, product-list, custom-variable

I have a customized variable called "brand" and I want to show all products with the same value as this variable.

It is possible to do this with the advanced search. but the look is not very good.

If anyone can help me, I would be grateful.

I'm using Magento 2.3.6

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code

```
$productcollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('brand','brand_value')
```

Answer (score 0):

Hoping you are getting a collection and you want to filter out the brand with a particular value

Suppose attr is 'brand' and you want to filter 'Nike' as brand from it

Use this `->addAttributeToFilter('brand', array('eq' => 'nike'));`

You can also do it in simple way - `->addAttributeToFilter('brand', 'nike');`

Happy coding